# Perform an Action when the app comes to foreground

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, android-background, onstart

I am developing an app which has to perform some background work. For that reason, I am using a Service. Now what I want to achieve suppose the user start the background work and while the work is loading then the user has an option to either minizine the app or wait till the loading is over.

After the loading is over I want to open another Activity. Now my issue supposes the user starts the loading and minimizes the app then when the loading is over the user has not yet returned to the app then if I start the Screen without even the user having my app in his view then the user might get interrupted with his work.

So what I want is when the loading is over, I want to only open if my app is visible to the user and if the app is not visible to the user then I want to wait till the user return back and only when the user returns back I want to open the Screen if the loading is over.

Now what I have thought is I should have a boolean which will track whether the app is visible to the user. On `onStop` I will set the boolean value to false and `onStart` I will set the value to true. And again `onStart` I will check if the loading is finished and if yes then I will open the Screen.

But I want to know whether there is a better way to achieve this? If yes then how. The reason I am looking for a better way is that I want to write a clean code for my app which might avoid bugs and crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly the scenario [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [RxJava](https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/rxjava-operators-just-range-from-repeat/#repeat) are for. Your activity will get the data only when the activity is visible. Your [Viwemodel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) will provide your live data to the activity only when your activity is available and it's lifecycle aware. You can also consider using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) if your app needs to continue to work even after your user closed your app, even if user restarts your app. It also comes with [Constraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints.html) to optimize your work based on Network, Battery life...and provides livedata for your Viewmodel to consume.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is something I was looking for. Will contact if if I find any further issue. Thanks once again.